# Force date / datetime to closest Friday Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with transactional data, each transaction has a date associated with it. Transaction can happen any day of the week, but I want to force the date to the Friday of the same week. In other words, Tuesday date of (9-17-2019) would show as 9-20-2019. I think I have done this before, but a) can't remember how  b) not sure if it was the easiest / most efficient.

Thanks for the help - Python beginner here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your DataFrame (*df*):

- has the source date in *Dat* column,
- the current Friday date should be saved in *Dat2* column,

execute:

```
df['Dat2'] = df.Dat + pd.offsets.Week(n=0, weekday=6) - pd.DateOffset(2)
```

Details:

- `+ pd.offsets.Week(n=0, weekday=6)` - shifts to the closest Sunday
  (*weekday=6*) but if the current weekday is already a Sunday, no shift
  takes place.
- `- pd.DateOffset(2)` - moves back 2 days.

Test: For a couple of initial days of September 2019 the result is:

```
          Dat       Dat2
0  2019-09-01 2019-08-30
1  2019-09-02 2019-09-06
2  2019-09-03 2019-09-06
3  2019-09-04 2019-09-06
4  2019-09-05 2019-09-06
5  2019-09-06 2019-09-06
6  2019-09-07 2019-09-06
7  2019-09-08 2019-09-06
8  2019-09-09 2019-09-13
9  2019-09-10 2019-09-13
10 2019-09-11 2019-09-13
11 2019-09-12 2019-09-13
12 2019-09-13 2019-09-13
13 2019-09-14 2019-09-13
14 2019-09-15 2019-09-13
15 2019-09-16 2019-09-20
```

So:

- *2019-09-01* (Sunday) is moved (back) to *2019-08-30*,
- for the next weekend (2-8.09) the current Friday is *2019-09-06*,

and so on.